# Como obter outros valores do item selecionado do Spinner além do mostrado?

Tags: java, android

**Dúvida:**

Como faço para buscar o valor do campo `handle` referente ao `nome` que foi selecionado no `Spinner` ?

**Cenário:**

Tabela `clientes`

Campos `_id, handle, nome`

O `ArrayList` do `Spinner` é criado da seguinte forma:

```
public ArrayList<String> getClientes(){

        sqLiteDatabase = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT nome FROM clientes ORDER BY nome", null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                clientes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return clientes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A informação que pode obter do item seleccionado do Spinner é apenas aquela que está guardada no ArrayList que é usado pelo Adapter.

Pelo que me é dado perceber o ArrayList apenas guarda a coluna ***nome***.

Defina uma classe que represente um cliente:

```
public class Cliente{

    private int id;
    private int handle;
    private String nome;

    public Cliente(int id, int handle, String nome){

        this.id = id;
        this.handle = handle;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getHandle(){
        return handle;
    }

    public String nome(){
        return nome;
    }

    //O que este método retornar é o que Spinner mostrará.
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Essa classe deverá ser o tipo usado pelo ArrayList a ser usado pelo Adapter.

Altere o método `getClientes()` para retornar `ArrayList<Cliente>`:

```
public ArrayList<Cliente> getClientes(){

    sqLiteDatabase = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY nome", null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            int handle = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("handle")));
            String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(id, handle, nome);
            clientes.add(cliente);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return clientes;
}
```

Obtenha o Cliente seleccionado com:

```
Cliente cliente = ((cliente)spinner.getSelectedItem());
```

e o handle com:

```
int handle = cliente.getHandle();
```

Comment: Perfeito. Além de dar certo, me ajudou entender outros detalhes ! Muito obrigado !

Comment: ramaral, só uma dúvida... sempre terá que ser criada uma classe para o ArrayList, ou existe uma forma alternativa ? O `ArrayList<?>` poderia funcionar ?

Comment: `ArrayList<?>` declara um ArrayList que pode conter um qualquer tipo(classe) de objecto. No entanto esse tipo tem de existir, tem de ter sido definido. Além que será necessário fazer o *cast* respectivo para ser possível aceder aos seus membros: `ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList();` `list.add(new Tipo1());` `list.add(new Tipo2());` `Tipo1 tipo1 = (Tipo1)list.get(0);`

Comment: Realmente, é mais trabalhoso e desorganizado ao meu ver ! Valeu ramaral !