# ListView com diferentes layouts por linhas, conforme valor filtrado

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma tabela única no BD, que contém os registros com campos como: `tipo, data, hora, cliente, historico`

Conforme o valor do `tipo`, o campo `cliente` é ou não obrigatório, ou seja, `vazio`.

Para criar uma `ListView` preciso ter os campos que ela irá exibir, mas terão casos que esse campo `cliente`, como outros mais, ficarão todos vazios.

Teria como eu gerar os registros da `ListView` exibindo os campos especificadamente por registro conforme seu o campo `tipo`, assim exibir somente o necessário pelo tipo de registro ?

Exemplo:

Se for tipo = 1, exibe os campos:

- TIPO - DATA - CLIENTE

Se for tipo = 2, exibe os campos:

- TIPO - HORA - HISTORICO

Comment: Parece-me que possa ter um problema de modelação dos dados, pois se são duas informações distintas normalmente estariam em duas tabelas distintas. Mas é difícil de dizer com a informação reduzida que tem na pergunta.

Comment: É basicamente o mesmo tipo de registro, só que varia alguns campos conforme o valor do campo `tipo`. Então quero esconder ou exibir os campos conforme o tipo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim é possível.

Para isso deverá ter/fazer:

- Uma classe que represente cada item(Cliente) com *"getters"* para cada um dos valores que quer mostrar.
- Um *custom adapter*.
- Um *layout* para cada tipo de linha.

No Adapter terá de sobrescrever os métodos

```
public int getViewTypeCount()
```

e

```
public int getItemViewType(int position)
```

O primeiro deve retornar o número de *views/layouts* diferentes que serão criados em `getView()`, o segundo o tipo referente ao *view/layout* a criar para a linha corrente.

O método `getView()` do Adapter deve ser implementado de forma a que, em função do valor retornado por `getItemViewType()`, crie o *layout* a usar e preencha as suas *views* de acordo com os valores no ArrayList(clientes):

```
public class ClientesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Cliente> Clientes;

    public ClientesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cliente> clientes) {
        super(context, 0, clientes);
        this.clientes = clientes;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      return clientes.get(position).getTipo();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (v == null) {

            // Cria a view em função do tipo
            if (type == 1) {
                // Layout para o tipo 1
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tipo1, parent, false);
        }
        else {
            // Layout para o tipo 2
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tipo2, parent, false);
        }

        //O cliente para esta linha
        Cliente cliente = clientes.get(position);

        if (type == 1) {
         // atribuir aqui os valores às views do layout_tipo1
        }else{
            // atribuir aqui os valores às views do layout_tipo2
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

O *adapter* é usado assim:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientes_list);
ArrayList<Clientes> clientes = getClientes(); 

ClientesAdapter clientesAdapter = new ClientesAdapter(this, clientes);
listView.setAdapter(clientesAdapter);
```

Terá de adaptar de acordo com as sua necessidades.

Comment: Em `Uma classe que represente cada item(Cliente) com "getters" para cada um dos valores que quer mostrar.` Seria uma classe, neste caso, que buscaria os registros (query com os joins) e ter os getters de todos os campos para que o adapter faça o filtro ?

Comment: Seria como a classe da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271828/2541) que dei a esta sua [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271801/2541).

Comment: Então não será ela que irá buscar os registros, será o `adapter` ?

Comment: Não, ela será a que recebe o registo referente a um cliente. Ela será usada pelo ArrayList(ArrayList<Cliente>) que contém todos os registos.

Comment: `private LayoutInflater inflater; e private ArrayList<Cliente> Clientes;` seriam dentro da class ?

Comment: Sim, editei a resposta.

Comment: posso abrir um chat ?

Comment: Se tem dúvidas em como implementar um ArrayAdapter personalizado(custom) veja este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoX_WJ_bS8c)

Comment: Acho que o `ctx` aqui seria o `context`: `inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: Sim. Copy e Paste de vários lados é o que dá :)

Comment: Aqui `ArrayList<Clientes> clientes = getClientes(); ` acho que seria `ArrayList<Clientes> clientes = ArrayList<>(); `

Comment: Aqui `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tipo1, parent, false);` ao invés de `LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.item, null);`. Qual seria o motivo ? Os tipos diferentes ?

Comment: Não, `getClientes()` será um método que irá ler o banco e retornar um ArrayList<Cliente>. Suponho que você já deve ter um método desse tipo feito.

Comment: Entendi ! Agora entendi porque estava me perdendo em certa parte. Faltava essa parte de buscar no banco.

Answer (score 2):

Na realidade só precisamos de subscrever o método getView do ArrayAdapter.
Talvez com este exemplo fique mais simples a ideia de controlar as views que se pretende exibir numa ListView através de um array adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>
{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects){
        super(context, 0, myObjects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
        }

               //Recupera o Objecto da lista através do método getItem
        MyObject myObject = getItem(position);

                ((TextView) convertView).findViewById(R.id.text_view_one);

                ((TextView) convertView).findViewById(R.id.text_view_two);

               //Inteiro vindo da base de dados
              int tipo = myObject.getTipo();

                If(tipo == 1){
                    textView1.setText(....);

                    //Esconde a text view
                    textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }else{
                    textView1.setText(....);
                    textView2.setText(....);
           }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fábio, selecione o código todo é pressione `CTRL+K` para formatar.

Comment: @wmsouza obrigado...

Comment: *"Na realidade só precisamos de subscrever o método getView (..)"* - Isso é verdade, no entanto, na minha resposta, quis seguir o que a  classe BaseAdapter preconiza para a sua implementação. Note que há casos em que a determinação do tipo de view a usar pode dar "mais trabalho"  sendo preferível ter um método para esse fim em vez de colocar essa lógica no `getView()`

Answer (score 1):

Eu precisava de um adapter que me proporcionasse o seguinte: ora, por escolha minha, setasse um layout específico pra quando eu recebo mensagens, ora um layout específico para quando eu envio a mensagem. Após muito tempo quebrando a cabeça tive esse insight:

```
package adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.stevenilson.appchat.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import objetos.Message;

public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
Context context;
public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public void add(Message message) {
    this.messages.add(message);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return messages.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return messages.get(i);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    MessageViewHolder holder = new MessageViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Message message = messages.get(i);
    if (message.isBelongsToCurrentUser()) {
        convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_message, null);
        holder.messageBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.messageBody.setText(message.getText());
    } else {
        convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.their_message, null);
        holder.avatar = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.messageBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.name.setText(message.getData().getName());
        holder.messageBody.setText(message.getText());
        GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.avatar.getBackground();
        drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(message.getData().getColor()));
    }
    return convertView;
}
}

class MessageViewHolder {
    public View avatar;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView messageBody;
}
```

Usando esse adapter junto de um objeto Message para os demais atributos:

```
package objetos;

import com.stevenilson.appchat.ChatMessage;

public class Message {
    private String text;
    private ChatMessage data;
    private boolean belongsToCurrentUser;
    public Message(String text, ChatMessage data, boolean belongsToCurrentUser) {
        this.text = text;
        this.data = data;
        this.belongsToCurrentUser = belongsToCurrentUser;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public ChatMessage getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public boolean isBelongsToCurrentUser() {
        return belongsToCurrentUser;
    }
}
```

Com isso instancio ambos em meu `main` e em cada método (`sendMessage` ou `receive`) eu trocava apenas o `boolean belongsToCurrentUser` para o adapter ter controle sobre o que fazer

```
sendMessage(View view){
    String texto = textMessage.getText().toString();


    belongsToCurrentUser = true;
    this.message.setText(texto);
    Message obMessage = new Message(texto, this.message, belongsToCurrentUser);


    if (texto.length() > 0) {

        messageAdapter.add(obMessage);
        this.message.setAction(ChatMessage.Action.SEND_ALL);
        this.message.setText(texto);
        this.socketTask.send(this.message);

    }

    listView.setSelection(listView.getCount() - 1);
}
```

Acho que por mais tarde que seja, esta resposta pode vir a ajudar alguém.