# Buscar valores de ListView customizado

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte `ListView` que foi gerado com um [adapter customizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272787/como-uma-listview-ter-linhas-com-diferentes-layouts-conforme-resultado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como buscar os valores (data, hora, historico, id, etc) do item com o `setOnItemLongClickListener`, pois preciso desses valores (ou ao menos o valor do `id` do item) para pesquisar no `SQLite` e abrir em outra tela para edição.

Até o momento testei da seguinte forma, mas só me trás a posição do item na lista:

```
this.ltvRegistros.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Editar");
                dialog.setMessage("Deseja editar o item ?");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        CRegistros item = (CRegistros) ltvRegistros.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Registro " + item.get_Id().toString() + " apagado !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        DBController ct = new DBController(getBaseContext());
                        ct.buscaRegistro(id);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Falha minha.

Estou puxando o `item.get_Id()` mas a activity que eu estava puxando não tem o campo associando `id`.
Fiz a associação e deu certo.

As vezes só de repassarmos os passos para descrever em uma pergunta, acabamos descobrindo por si só.

Irei deixar a pergunta como arquivo caso ajude um próximo.

Me desculpem.